# Evaluating $ \lim_{x\to 0} ({\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}} - {\frac{2}{x^2}})$ without L'hopital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} ({\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}} - {\frac{2}{x^2}})$$

I know I can so some L'hopital's rule and get  the answer, but is there another way, more clever? Like with Taylor expansion? I tried it and got $\infty*0$

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{24} < 1-\cos x < \frac{x^2}{2}$ for $0 < \lvert x\rvert < 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By replacing $x$ with $2z$, we are left with:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2 z}-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)&=&\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(z-\sin z)(z+\sin z)}{z^4+o(z^4)}\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\left(\frac{z^3}{6}+o(z^3)\right)(2z+o(z))}{z^4+o(z^4)}\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 2):

A convenient notation that I will use here: $o(f(x))$ is a symbol for an unspecified function such that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{o(f(x))}{f(x)}=0$. For example, $o(x^2)$ could stand for $x^3$. This is called "little oh notation".

With this included, let's start with some algebra:

$$\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}-\frac{2}{x^2}=\frac{x^2-2+2\cos(x)}{x^2(1-\cos(x))}.$$

The idea: determine what order the denominator vanishes to, and then calculate the numerator to that order. The denominator turns out to vanish to order $4$, since both $x^2$ and $1-\cos(x)$ vanish to order $2$. So the numerator, computed to order $4$, is

$$x^2-2+2(1-x^2/2+x^4/24+o(x^4))=x^2-2+2-x^2+x^4/12+o(x^4)=x^4/12+o(x^4).$$

The denominator, computed to order $4$ (i.e. to leading order) is $\frac{x^4}{2}+o(x^4)$. So the ratio is

$$\frac{x^4/12+o(x^4)}{x^4/2+o(x^4)}.$$

Can you see how to finish the argument from here? Hint: the way you finish it is the same as it would be if you replaced the $o(x^4)$ with $x^5$.

What we're doing here is actually very similar to L'Hopital's rule; in fact this produces a proof that if you apply L'Hopital's rule to that function 4 times, you'll get the limit.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} {\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}} - {\frac{2}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0} {{x^2-2+2 \cdot \cos(x)} \over {(1-\cos(x)) \cdot x^2}}$$

Take advantage of the Taylor/Maclurian expansion for cosine and substitute for each instance of cosine. Note that some of the terms cancel.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {{x^4/12+O(x^6)} \over {x^4/2+O(x^6)}}={1 \over 6}$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative view is the following.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1- \cos x} - \frac{2}{x^{2}} &= \frac{1}{1 - \left(1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2!} - \frac{x^{4}}{4!} + \cdots \right)} - \frac{2}{x^{2}} \\
&= \frac{2}{x^{2}} \, \left[ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2 \, x^{2}}{4!} + \frac{2 \, x^{4}}{6!} - \cdots } - 1 \right].
\end{align}
Now, by "long division" it is seen that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1 - \frac{2 \, x^{2}}{4!} + \frac{2 \, x^{4}}{6!} - \cdots } = 1 + \frac{2 \, x^{2}}{4!} + \frac{3 \, x^{4}}{6!} + \mathcal{O}(x^{6})
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1 - \cos x} - \frac{2}{x^{2}} &= \frac{2}{x^{2}} \, \left[ \left( 1 + \frac{2 \, x^{2}}{4!} + \frac{3 \, x^{4}}{6!} + \mathcal{O}(x^{6}) \right) - 1 \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{3!} \, \left[ 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{20} + \mathcal{O}(x^{4}) \right]. 
\end{align}
By taking the limit as $x \to 0$ leads to
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \left\{ \frac{1}{1- \cos x} - \frac{2}{x^{2}} \right\} = \frac{1}{3!}.
\end{align}

Comment: Can you spell out where the $3$ in the second to last line of your first block came from? Alternately you could suppress it, since apparently it doesn't contribute.

Comment: @Ian The term in question is obtained from the process of "long division" of the inverse series in the previous line. As to the supression of the term it is often necessary to keep a few power terms to see how the remainder of the series behaves. In this case not really necessary, but in keeping with a particular practice it is good for viewing.

Comment: I know how I would derive it, but I don't think it's clear in your writeup that that is actually what you did.